# Importind data from a txt file with Python

Tags: python, import, transform, txt

I have 12 data block on a txt file following the next format:

```
Record No. : B00, Factor: 0.0
  0.0305  0.1114  0.1524  0.1368  0.0708  0.0231  0.1089  0.1562
  0.1454  0.0819  0.0143  0.1051  0.1600  0.1549  0.0946  0.0039
```

And I would like to import it to python looking like this:

```
B00 = {"Factor : 0.0", "Data : ( 0.0305, 0.1114, 0.1524, 0.1368, 0.0708, 0.0231, 0.1089, 0.1562,
  0.1454, 0.0819, 0.0143, 0.1051, 0.1600, 0.1549, 0.0946, 0.0039)"}
```

As you can see there are float numbers, The name of the data (that I want to convert into a dictionary) is a combination of numbers and characters (so basically, a string), and the data is a list of float numbers where I would have to replace "  " (2 blank spaces) in the txt. for ", " (a coma and 1 blank space) in python.

After that, what I'm going to do is multiply data * factor in each of the 12 data blocks, so I'll probably put the dictionaries on a list for iterate through each one doing that operation, but I think I can figure that last part on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to process over the txt file? Could you upload your txt? Maybe less blocks, but full format please.

Comment: You mean like this:?                   Record No.:A03,  Scale Factor:18.5,  Data Number:39
                0.1778  0.1897  0.1819  0.0505  0.0341  0.1903  0.1854  0.2297
                0.0549  0.0198  0.2203  0.1551  0.3135  0.0305  0.1273  0.2973
                0.0600  0.4784  0.0727  0.3568  0.4892  0.1946  0.8324  0.3811
                0.8757  0.9757  0.8432  1.6432  1.2054  2.0811  2.1757  2.4405
                3.4865  3.3514  5.3784  7.1622 10.8649  9.1081  2.2676

Comment: This is just one block, right? Does your txtfile have multiple data blocks?

Comment: Yes, 12 more just like this one, but with different values